# Bootstrap 5 beta dropdown issue calling from javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdown that was working in bootstrap 4, but now in bootstrap 5 (beta) it is no longer working. What I am trying to do is open a specific dropdown from a secondary button but this no longer works any more due to the changes they made in bootstrap 5. There is a fiddle to demonstrate. When you click the main button it works fine but when you click the second button it has an error, this method of just calling the dropdown show method from anywhere worked perfectly in bootstrap 4. How can I get it to work in bootstrap 5, there are mentions of a 'reference' option in the docs but all the examples in the docs are only for data-attributes, not for JS. I have tried a bunch of stuff but nothing works.
Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/6hbcp9xm/

HTML:

```
  <div class="col">
    <div id="test" class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button id="testbtn">
      test
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#testbtn").on("click", function(){
    $("#test").dropdown("show");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The id you tried to show was wrapped around the first dropdown button. This makes it try to show the button, which is already shown so the script runs into an error.

Use `toggleClass` in combination with the class of the dropdown which is `.dropdown-menu`.

```
$("#testbtn").on("click", function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nzx1c04y

Comment: Thank you for your input, but unfortunately it doesn't really fix the overall problem. It's just a hack to get past one phase of it. When the dropdown is opened with the second button it completely breaks the dropdown functionality (as in clicking anywhere outside doesn't close it again, it can only be closed by clicking the same button). I think I'm just gonna have to forget about the second button now with bootstrap 5. Thanks for the help though.